# Trying to import data (.tsv file) into custom tables using SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

As a part of project, I did change the field names and lengths of 2 columns. And the since I moved these database tables into Production environment. The data in those 2 columns is lost. How can i upload the data into those 2 columns. I got the copy of the file (*.tsv file). Its quite huge around 200 MB. And the only tool i got is SQL developer.

What are the best possible ways to import these 2 columns in production environment.

Here's how the updated table structure is-
2 fields which i updated are- RPTC_PAY_NBR and RPTC_PAYROLL_NBR

desc PS_RPTC_TAX_WAGE
Name               Null     Type

---

PAYGROUP           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(3)
FILE_NBR           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)
CHECK_DT                    DATE
WEEK_NBR           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
RPTC_PAYROLL_NBR   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
CHECK_NBR          NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
PAY_END_DT                  DATE
EMPLID             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(11) 
EMPL_RCD_NBR       NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
VOID_IND           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)
RPTC_PAY_NBR       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)
RPTC_CUR_FEDTAX    NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_CUR_FEDWGS    NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_CUR_FUTAWGS   NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_FUTA_ER_LIMIT NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_CUR_EE_MCWG   NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_CUR_ER_MCWG   NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_CUR_MC_SUR    NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_CUR_MC_SURWG  NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_CUR_EE_SSWG   NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_CUR_MEDTAX    NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_CUR_ER_SSWG   NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_SS_RATE       NOT NULL NUMBER(16,4) 
RPTC_SS_TAX_LMT    NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_SS_TXBL_LMT   NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_CUR_ER_SSMEDW NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_CUR_SSTAX     NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_CUR_SSMED     NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2) 
RPTC_YTD_MED_UNC   NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2)

### RPTC_YTD_SS_UNC    NOT NULL NUMBER(14,2)

Please advise.

Comment: Please note, I already tried to import the file using the import utility in SQL developer. But somehow its throwing error-

Comment: "Table already exist"